# Do i need an api key to access the new freebase images?

Tags: ios, freebase

I have a database of people in my iOS app with their images being dowloaded from freebase.com Today i noticed that the images are not downloading any more.  I checked and i see that google redesigned and reorganized freebase and now the images include a key.  Right now i have image url stored in core data like this 
http://img.freebase.com/api/trans/image_thumb/m/03s07kd?maxheight=240&maxwidth=300

To use the new format do i have to get an api key and include that with every image request or i can just get the link and change it in my database?  I am not making any other calls to the database just the image from the url.

I just tested and i can change the link to 
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image/m/03s07kd?maxheight=240&maxwidth=300
which works.  I am also noticing now that the images are much lower quality then they were before.  How do i get the same quality images that i was getting before?
I want to make sure that this won't happen again and do it properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a whole set of documentation at: https://developers.google.com/freebase/

Basically, as I understand it, if you don't include your own API key, you'll be working off a small pool of quota shared with all other API users who aren't sending keys with their requests.  This means it could work in the morning, but not the evening when quota is exhausted or it works some days, but not others.

Don't forget to include the required attribution to Freebase if you aren't already including it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I got the api key and now it's working.  Will have to update my database with the new url.